# preg_replace vs ereg_replace vs str_replace On This Particular Case

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

Using PHP, I want to generate custom MySQL dump file (due to cannot use exec and a few other reasons).

I found these 2 similar solutions:

1. https://www.kvcodes.com/2017/10/php-create-mysql-backup
2. https://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php

The different part that I want to highlight is:

Link 1:

```
$row[$j] = preg_replace("#\n#", "\\n", $row[$j])
```

Link 2:

```
$row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j])
```

I know that `ereg_replace()` is deprecated. I also assume that there's typo in solution Link 1 which should be:

```
$row[$j] = preg_replace("\n", "\\n", $row[$j])
```

But then in my solution, I simply use:

```
$row[$j] = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $row[$j])
```

How could I be wrong by using `str_replace()?` I've tested dumping several complex data (json, coding, html syntax) and all seems ok. Could there some special case that `str_replace()` would handle differently than `preg_replace()`?

Comment: There is no typo in link 1. Look at the manual you need delimiters. `\v` is likely best in the regex for any new line character.

Comment: I have been using str_replace() in most of my projects. (no problem at all)

Comment: `ereg_replace()` was **removed** in PHP7. If you are still using a version of PHP that has it the first thing you should do is upgrade it to PHP8

Comment: @user3783243, not typo means he want to remove all comment? But shouldn't it be `"#*.#"`?

Comment: No, that is replacing all new line characters with an escaped new line character. The `#`s are delimiters, not part of regex. https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

> If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular  expressions), you should use this function instead of preg_replace().

If `str_replace()` does what you need, then use it. It will be faster than `preg_replace()`.

The simple string replacement is not as intelligent as a regular expression, so test it thoroughly for your application.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid for. In case my test not really thoroughly. But given the simple pattern to be replaced (\n), I can stick to str_replace right? Or by using regex, it also cater situation like different platform? anything

Comment: `\n` is not a new line in Windows. You should use regex if you need to escape every new line regardless of platform.

Comment: @user3783243 thank you for the clarification. So I change my solution to `$row[$j] = preg_replace("\n", "\\n", $row[$j])` to be safe on any platform

Comment: @Coisox Use `\v` for any vertical whitespace which should be newlines on any platform. Again though you **NEED** delimiters.